# Calling method that returns tv.getText() returns different value as simply using tv.getText()?

Tags: java, android

I build a method to retrieve the text inside a TextView. My problem is that when I call the method to retrieve the text it always returns "". It's easier to see the problem by looking at the code:

```
    public TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      ...
      tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
    }

    public String getResult() {
      return tv.getText().toString();
    }

    public void test() {
      System.out.println("A:"+tv.getText().toString()); // Returns text
      System.out.println("B:"+getResult()); // Always returns ""
```

Shouldn't getResult() be equivalent to tv.getText().toString()? How can they return different values?

Comment: your implementation is correct, can you please post some more code , so that we can see that where are you calling the test() and what value you are setting to the textview.

Comment: From where do you call `test()`?

Comment: Looks like they should print the same thing, unless getResult() method is overridden in a subclass and this code is being run in that subclass.